# C# not all rectangles are drawn in Image with height of around 70k px

Tags: c#, image, list, draw, drawrectangle

So I have around 160 images of the size 2048px x 512px. The images are gray images which i check for white areas, the rectangles around the areas are safed in a list. I now want to stitch the images together and draw the rectangles afterwards, I update the y position of each rectangle so i can draw them at the right position.

The stitching and updating the y position works fine. The stitched image is around 2048px x 80kpx.
I have 11 white areas that are detected, but only 3 rectangles are drawn even though while debugging all 11 should be drawn.

The first 3 rectangles are in the first 30k y-axis px, the others are starting at 45k px. When I change the code so that I start with picture 60, the first 3 rectangles are of course not drawn, but the other 8 are drawn.

Does anyone of you have an idea how to fix the issue?

```
public void GenerateImageMap()
    {

        StichtedImageTemp = new Image<Bgr, byte>(ImgWidth, ImgHeight * (GrayImageMap.Count));
        for (int i = 0; i < GrayImageMap.Count; i++)
        {
            StichtedImageTemp.ROI = new System.Drawing.Rectangle(0, i * ImgHeight, ImgWidth, ImgHeight);
            GrayImageMap[i].Convert<Bgr,byte>().CopyTo(StichtedImageTemp);
            CvInvoke.cvResetImageROI(StichtedImageTemp);
        }

        StichtedImageTemp.Save("GrayImageMap.png");
    }

public void GenerateDefectMap(List<Rectangle> RectangleItems) {
        GenerateImageMap();
        foreach (var item in RectangleItems)
        {
            StichtedImageTemp.Draw(item.GetRectangle, new Bgr(Color.Aquamarine), 3);
        }
        StichtedImageTemp.Save("GrayDefectMap.png");
    }
```

Comment: You can't easily create bitmaps of arbitrary sizes..

Comment: Hmm do you have a different solution that would work? The 160 images are just the beginning... In the end there will be even more and i want a stable algorithm for a high number of pictures if possible. I would really appreciate any idea, thank you!

Comment: Unfortunately, you're asking for it using standard image manipulation routines for something that big.

Comment: Because i don't know an alternative, that's why i'm asking for help

Comment: Well there is a limit of 32k that applies to many or most parameters of GDI calls and also Winforms controls..  In addition you can't create very large bitmaps since they would need too much consecutive ram. The workaround is to create ready made portions that stay within the limits and then stich them together with an external library or tool. Google for 'c# very large bitmaps'..

Answer (score 0):

You dont give enough source. For example, how does calling GenerateImageMap in GenerateDefectMap influence anything, it doesn't pass or modify the RectangleItems and only seems to operate on GrayImageMap, which is presumably global or something, who knows.

Personally, I wouldn't use System.Drawing methods, or you will have to be careful with interpolations at the edges etc. I would convert manually (pixel by pixel), which would be logically much simpler than the tupple system you have chosen. That's my opinion anyway.

Comment: I use GenerateImageMap to create the StichtedImageTemp Image so I can draw my rectangles in it. The modification of the rectangle y axis is happening in a different function, which pretty much gets a rectangle as an input, and returns a modified rectangle which has a different y axis which is beeing calculated by adding the y axis with the multiplication of the number of pictures that were scanned before the current white area was found. I do not understand what you mean with converting manually, can you please try to describe it a little more? Thank you